# Netsuite Case When Saved Search Formula including division

Tags: oracle, formula, netsuite

I am fairly new to NetSuite, and looking to move a report nomally ran in excel

I am trying to write a Transaction Saved Search looking at estimating When new stock needs to be ordered based on the last months sales by comparing stock on hand, quantity sold, lead time, and estimated number of weeks stock on hand.

I am running into an issue with this formula:

`CASE WHEN ({item.quantityonhand} / (NVL({quantity} / 30,0))) < {item.locationleadtime} then 1 else 0 end`

The type is Formula(Numeric). I have spent ages tweaking as i was previously getting the Invalid Expression error, but i am at least now getting a result - although not the one i wanted!

The report i have written is using Group & Max summary types, and i initially had written the code with a SUM on the {quantity} field, but this doesn't appear to work. My thought was that I want the sum of quantity for all transactions for each item to be calculated.

I have spent so long looking at this i am now out of ideas. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Mark

[Saved Search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBy9r.png)

Comment: What filters have you set in your Criteria tab?  What results are you expecting?  What are your actual results?

Comment: comparing a quantity to a number of days looks odd. Can you write out your formula (ignoring Netsuite)

Comment: Backing up what others have said. Unfortunately, we'll need more information to solve this.